# What's a good way to mix RSS feeds using Python?

Tags: python, django, rss, feed, parsing

SimplePie lets you merge feeds together:

http://simplepie.org/wiki/tutorial/sort_multiple_feeds_by_time_and_date

Is there anything like this in the Python world? The Universal Feed Parser documentation doesn't say anything about merging multiple feeds together.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://github.com/dustin/snippets/blob/master/python/net/http/combiner.py) may be a good start for you.  I wrote it a long time ago for one very specific combination, but I don't think I wrote it *too* specifically for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

[Planet](http://www.planetplanet.org/) is a feed aggregator written in Python. Its development is basically dead, but the code lives on in several forks, including Planet Venus.

Comment: SO seems to have issues with a link at the beginning of the answer. The URL for Planet Venus is http://intertwingly.net/code/venus/ .

Answer (score 1):

**[Atomisator](http://atomisator.ziade.org/)** is a data aggregator framework. Its purpose is to provide an engine to build any kind of data by merging several sources of data. It was developed as an example application in the book Expert Python Programming. You can use different In- and Output Formats. An RSS aggregartor is part of the examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Yahoo pipes for that task. It's a set a very powerful tools. I havo pipes join feeds based on certain criteria, and have it generate a compliant rss feed that i then process with universal feed parser.